# Using grep/sed for any length patterns between two words

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I have some directory called mydirectory with a bunch of text files containing the words 'SAVE' 'ME!' multiple times so I want it to print all the times for this specific pattern `'SAVE'|ANYTHING HERE, FOR ANY AMOUNT OF CHARACTERS|'ME'|Any non-zero amount of !s|'`

To do this, I came up with `sed -n '/SAVE/,/ME!\{1\}/p' mydirectory/*` but this did not work, does anybody know how to do this? I can only use sed and grep for this.

File:

```
SAVE US OR JUST ME!!
BRAINSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SAVE US OR JUST ME
BRAINSSSSSSSSSSSSS
SAVE ME!
BRAINNNNNNNNNNNNS
SAVE ME
```

Desired Output

```
SAVE US OR JUST ME!!
SAVE ME!
```

Comment: You want *what?* Please give an example of such a text file, and what you want to print.

Comment: Why can't you use `find`?

Comment: @Beta For example, lets say a file contains "SAVE US, OR JUST SAVE ME!!" it should return this whole statement since SAVE|Any Pattern|ME! is satisfied. On the other hand, "SAVE ME" would not as it does not have >= 1 exclamation points. I added an example above.

Comment: `sed -n '/SAVE.*ME!/p'`

Comment: Simple `grep 'SAVE.*ME' file`

Answer (score 1):

```
$ grep -E '^SAVE.*ME!+$' file
```

output:

```
SAVE US OR JUST ME!!
SAVE ME!
```

anchors the pattern to the beginning and end, which I guess what you want.